# mongodb aggregate populate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using two tables Event and Instance and their Schema Structure,

**Event table:**

```
{
   name:
   description:
   event_instance: {"Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Instance'}
}
```

**Instance table:**

```
{
   from_date:
   to_date:
}
```

I need to get counts by grouping event table using the from_date by accessing the Instance Table using the event_instance refObj field in Event table.

**Sample Code:**

```
exports.stats = function(req,res,next){
async.parallel([function(callback){
EventModel.aggregate([{
$match: queryObj
},{
$group:{
_id:{
  "$from_date"     //field from Instance table     
},
count: {
  $sum: 1
}
.....
```

Comment: Yeah. You're looking for Joins (for about the 10,000th customer). MongoDB does not do joins. Mongoose does not do joins, it just "pretends" to do so. So re-think your schema design. You are doing it wrong. Or go use a RDBMS which does things the way you are thinking. But maybe not optimally. It actually is the "trade-off" between the two that "should" have been your tech choice decision. And not "MongoDB" or "RDBMS" is cool right now. Some of us make choices based on merit.

Comment: any possible to do this